# How to mount USB3.0-Camera?

Tags: usb, mount, camera

I am new to Ubuntu and I want to work with OpenCV on my USB-3.0 Camera. 
I have the problem, that Ubuntu doesnt see it as an camera?
The output from lshw is in my attached picture.
Is it right, that ubuntu see it wrong?
How can i mount it correctly? 
Thanks in advance

[lshw-Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUZ3p.png)

[lsusb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dns2H.png)

lsusb-output:
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 2560:cld1

Camera:  See3CAM_CU135 from e-consystems
Ubuntu 18.04

dmesg-output:

```
[12390.573045] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci-hcd
[12390.584376] usb 4-1: LPM exit latency is zeroed, disabling LPM.
[12390.585285] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2560, idProduct=c1d1
[12390.585546] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[12390.585580] usb 4-1: Product: See3CAM_CU135
[12390.585599] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: e-con systems
[12390.585617] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 0E24480C
[12390.613855] hid-generic 0003:2560:C1D1.0001: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [e-con systems See3CAM_CU135] on usb-xhci-hcd.11.auto-1/input2
[12390.685248] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device See3CAM_CU135 (2560:c1d1)
[12390.688372] input: See3CAM_CU135 as /devices/platform/usb1/fe900000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.11.auto/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/input/input3
[12390.688919] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[12390.688931] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
```

Comment: Does it appear in: `lsusb`? What are the exact details from lsusb? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please copy/paste the outputs and add them to the question as text. Then I can see it. :~)

Comment: It is the See3CAM_CU135 from e-consystems. The wrote in their description, that the camera is plug and play for linux... Am I right, that my board thinks the camera is HID?

Comment: Try runing `tail -f /var/log/dmesg` in an terminal and then insert the usb camera. The lines output when inserting the camera should identify it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `dmesg` log, the camera is detected successfully:

```
[12390.585580] usb 4-1: Product: See3CAM_CU135
[12390.585599] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: e-con systems
[12390.585617] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 0E24480C
[12390.613855] hid-generic 0003:2560:C1D1.0001:
```

The camera is `v4l2` compatible, so you can base any `v4l2` application like `guvcview`, `cheese`, etc... to demonstrate some of the features of this camera. *OpenCV* is also compatible since it uses `v4l2` to access the camera.

Comment: What line in `dmesg` output does show that the camera is v4l2 compatibility?

Comment: Most of the USB cameras have UVC compliance. So you could use any V4L2 application to access UVC compliant cameras.